# Recommendations for: The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, dbcontext, edmx

I have a database with over 100 dables. I decided to split the EF model into three different ones. There are several tables which appear in more than one model. After using the EF 5.X DbContext Generator, I've got the POCO classes.

This template generates repeated classes (the ones that appear in more than one model) but with different namespace. After trying to query one of this ones I got the following error:

```
The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type
```

After facing this problem I believe I have two alternatives:

1. Edit CSDL, MSL, SSDL files to rename the entities. In this case I would append the context names as a prefix to the entities.
2. Edit the EF 5.x DbContext Generator to edit the name of the POCO classes that would be generated. In this case I would also append the context names as a prefix to the POCO classes.

My question goes as follows: Which option should I follow? And what do I need to do according to the selected option. And if none of the options is valid, what do you recommend me to do?

Comment: There is no "best" answer for this problem. You must find solution which best fits your needs. Another way you didn't mention is modifying generator to not create class which already exists again.

Comment: I know there is not an specific answer for this question but any advice would be helpful. Do you know how can i achieve to edit DbContext generator template so it won't create classes which already exist? I was trying to figure it out but couldnt understand at all the code behind the template.

Answer (score 1):

If you edit the t4 templates (option 2) all classes will be affected. By editing class names (which you can do in the designer surfaces) you can change only those classes that are common in more contexts.

So if the overlapping classes are few, I'd opt for option 1. I am doing the same in a similar scenario where some tables are included in more than one context (business, authorization, reporting, ...), and only the context where the class has its original name is for CUD actions on that class. Besides, I wouldn't like all of my classes to have prefixes.

Comment: This solutions seems being really useful but I still have another problem to face. Because I splitted the db model into three different models, I'm using the "using namespace" in the csdl files to reference the entities of another model. With this I can't rename the names of the entities because they won't fit the name they have in the other model. Any idea? (i splitted the model because of performance, i don't know if this applies to EF 5)

Comment: This sounds like something you should not do. Are we on the same track here? I was talking about, say, a `User` entity in the business context and an `AuthorizationUser` entity in the authorization context. Both map to the same table, but apart from that they have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: I understand you. In my case, what do you recommend me to do? I've been stucked on this for several days without finding any solution.

Comment: I would rename the few common classes and let each of them have a main context and have a read-only function in other contexts.

Comment: On my way through finding a solution for this problem, I put every model in different assemblies so there would be no repeated classes. After making this change, I'm getting this error: The DbContext class cannot be used with models that have multiple entity sets per type (MEST). Do I need to quit using DbContext and POCO?

Comment: I think this is something for a new question where you can show the details of your model and you can elaborate on why you want to use MEST.

Comment: I found a solution to this problem. Let me share it. What I did was to generate 3 different models (in different projects) from my database and generating POCO classes with EF 5.X DbContext generator. I left the csdl, msl, ssdl files intact (did not make any references between them with the "using namespace" statement. I copied POCOs to another project (another 3 projects, one for each model) and generated views for each one. Three different assemblies was the key solution for my problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2):

I deleted the **.edmx** file and re-created it.
This fixes the problem. Not sure if this helps you.